# VB.Net SQL Connection problems

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am working on a Windows CE application programmed in VB. I am trying to add in an SQL Connection so the application will access the database and retrieve the required information. I have tried a lot of different connection strings with no luck. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? Or suggest a way forward as at this stage any suggestions would help. Thanks in advance

The code below is the code I am using to try and access the SQLDatabase

```
Public Class SQLTest
    Dim sqlCMD As SqlCommand
    Dim myDA As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim myDataSet As DataSet
    Private Sub SQLTest_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        '"Data Source=.;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SqlDatabase.mdf"
        Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.1.62,1433;Initial Catalog=CASILynasFulfilment;User ID=rfgun;Password=Casiuk2012*;")
        ' Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.1.62;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\master.mdf")
        Dim cmd As String = "SELECT * FROM [Order]"
        'Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Order]")
        con.Open()
        sqlCMD = New SqlCommand(cmd, con)
        Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader = sqlCMD.ExecuteReader()
        While sqlReader.Read()
            MsgBox(sqlReader.Item(0) & "  -  " & sqlReader.Item(1) & "  -  " & sqlReader.Item(2))
        End While
        sqlReader.Close()
        sqlCMD.Dispose()
        con.Close()

        'Automatically generates DeleteCommand, UpdateCommand and InsertCommand for DataAdapter object  
        ' Dim builder As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(myDA)
        '  myDataSet = New DataSet()
        '  myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "MyTable")
        '  DataGrid1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("MyTable").DefaultView
        '  con.Close()
        '   con = Nothing
    End Sub
```

The image below is the error I am getting.

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. In the Configuration Manager Named Pipes were not enabled so it would not allow a connection to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Are You writing your connection string manually?

if yes, then don't do that

just open youre server explorer

select your server name (which is your machine name)

select your db file

and test connection by clcik on 'test connection button'

if success, then just copy the connection string by righr click on your db file

and paste it where you required it

Comment: Thanks, I have done that for the connection string so I know now that it is connecting but I am still getting the same General Network Error.